# Does `:` as the first character of a symbol name have a special meaning?

Tags: symbols, keywords

If I run

```
(plist-get '(A  4  B  3) 'B)
```

I get 3 as expected. I understand that I must quote B, otherwise

```
(plist-get '(A  4  B  3) B)
```

causes an error:

> elisp--eval-last-sexp: Symbol’s value as variable is void: B

However, I do not understand why these two versions work (even without quoting :B)

```
(plist-get '(:A  4  :B  3) ':B)  ;; works
(plist-get '(:A  4  :B  3) :B)   ;; also works !
```

Does `:` have a special meaning ?

Comment: See e.g [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/59783/how-to-use-keyword-symbols-in-emacs-lisp) and [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/12142/use-of-keyword-symbols-in-property-lists).

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They’re called keywords. They are a type of symbol that evaluates to themselves, so they don’t need to be quoted (as you discovered). Check out [chapter 2.4.4 Symbol Type](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Symbol-Type.html) of the Emacs Lisp manual, which describes them.

```
   A symbol whose name starts with a colon (‘:’) is called a “keyword
symbol”.  These symbols automatically act as constants, and are normally
used only by comparing an unknown symbol with a few specific
alternatives.  *Note Constant Variables::.
```